# how we handle onBackPressed in an android Service

Tags: android, android-service

I develop an application of cracking screen i run an android service to showing crack screen on home screen now i want to repair when user pressed back button on five times while our service is running on top and show crack screen how can i handle back button within a service please help me for this how we handle back button in a services like this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ultimate.apps.crackscreen2

Comment: cant u detect whether a button has been pressed 5 times using a timer and then do what u want in the service?

Comment: how we detect back button during running a service

Comment: @AhmadJoyia, hi did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score -4):

```
  public void onBackPressed() {
                super.onBackPressed();
               //Do ur operation here

        }
```

Comment: My dear i already tells that I use service and in service there is no any onBackPressed() method in android service